# Problem when branching Sklearn Pipiline into a GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to build a pipeline with my own functions. To do so I inherited BaseEstimator and TransformerMixin from sklearn base and defined my own transform methods.

When I do pipeline.fit(X,y), it works fine.

The problem is when I try to create a GridSearchCV object with the pipeline. I get the following error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (730,36) (228,) (730,36).

730 Is just the number of lines of matrix X divided by 'cv' = 2, the number of folds I choose for the cross-validation in the GridSearchCV.

I have no idea how to debug that. I've tried some prints in the middle of my functions, and the result is pretty weird.

I'm attaching the functions I created as well as the pipeline. I'd be really glad if someone could help.

Here are the functions I created for the Pipeline:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class MissingData(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):


    def fit( self, X, y = None  ):
        return self

    def transform(self, X , y = None, strategies = ( "most_frequent", "mean") ):
        print('Started MissingData')
        X_ = X.copy()

        #Categorical Variables handling
        categorical_variables = list(X_.select_dtypes(include=['category','object']))
        imp_category = SimpleImputer(strategy = strategies[0])
        X_[categorical_variables] = pd.DataFrame(imp_category.fit_transform(X_[categorical_variables]))


        #Numeric varialbes handling
        numerical_variables = list(set(X_.columns) - set(categorical_variables))
        imp_numerical = SimpleImputer(strategy = strategies[1])
        X_[numerical_variables] = pd.DataFrame(imp_numerical.fit_transform(X_[numerical_variables]))
        print('Finished MissingData')


        print('Inf: ',X_.isnull().sum().sum())
        return X_

class OHEncode(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y = None  ):
        return self

    def encode_and_drop_original_and_first_dummy(self,df, feature_to_encode):
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[feature_to_encode] , prefix = feature_to_encode, drop_first=True) #Drop first equals true will take care of the dummies variables trap
        res = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
        res = res.drop([feature_to_encode], axis=1)
        return(res) 

    def transform(self, X , y = None, categorical_variables  = None ):
        X_ = X.copy()
        if categorical_variables == None:
            categorical_variables  = list(X_.select_dtypes(include=['category','object']))
        print('Started Encoding')
        #Let's update the matrix X with the one hot ecoded version of all features in categorical_variables
        for feature_to_encode in categorical_variables:
            X_ = self.encode_and_drop_original_and_first_dummy(X_ , feature_to_encode)
        print('Finished Encoding')
        print('Inf: ',X_.isnull().sum().sum())
        return X_
```

Here is the Pipeline with the GridSearchCV:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
pipeline = Pipeline([('MissingData', MissingData()), ('OHEncode', OHEncode()) , 
          ('scaler', StandardScaler()) , ('pca', pca), ('rf', LinearRegression())])

parameters = {'pca__n_components': [5, 15, 30, 45, 64]}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, cv = 2)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

And finally here is the full output including my prints and the error:

```
Started MissingData
Finished MissingData
Inf:  57670
Started Encoding
Finished Encoding
Inf:  26280
Started MissingData
Finished MissingData
Inf:  0
Started Encoding
C:\Users\menoci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py:765: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  updated_mean = (last_sum + new_sum) / updated_sample_count
C:\Users\menoci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py:706: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice.
  result = op(x, *args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\menoci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

  FitFailedWarning)
Finished Encoding
Inf:  0
Started MissingData
Finished MissingData
Inf:  57670
Started Encoding
Finished Encoding
Inf:  26280
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-f78b56dad89d> in <module>
     15 
     16 #pipeline.set_params(rf__n_estimators = 50)
---> 17 grid.fit(X, y)
     18 
     19 #rf_val_predictions = pipeline.predict(X)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    710                 return results
    711 
--> 712             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    713 
    714         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1151     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1152         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1153         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1154 
   1155 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    689                                for parameters, (train, test)
    690                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 691                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    692 
    693                 if len(out) < 1:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 
-> 1007             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1008                 pass
   1009 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    833                 return False
    834             else:
--> 835                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    836                 return True
    837 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    752         with self._lock:
    753             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 754             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    755             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    756             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    207     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    208         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 209         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    210         if callback:
    211             callback(result)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    588         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    589         # arguments in memory
--> 590         self.results = batch()
    591 
    592     def get(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    542     else:
    543         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 544         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    545         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    546         if return_train_score:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    589         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    590     else:
--> 591         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    592 
    593     error_msg = ("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) "

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     87                                       *args, **kwargs)
     88             else:
---> 89                 score = scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     90             scores[name] = score
     91         return scores

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
    369 def _passthrough_scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs):
    370     """Function that wraps estimator.score"""
--> 371     return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
    372 
    373 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    611         Xt = X
    612         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 613             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    614         score_params = {}
    615         if sample_weight is not None:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in transform(self, X, copy)
    804         else:
    805             if self.with_mean:
--> 806                 X -= self.mean_
    807             if self.with_std:
    808                 X /= self.scale_

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (730,36) (228,) (730,36)
```

Comment: each of your transformers produces an array with different dimention. Thus, what I recommend you is to get the results from each one independently and check the output dimentions (e.g. `x = MissingData()` and then `x.fit(...`).

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Ghanem.
If that was the case, pipeline.fit alone shouldn't work, right? But it works.

Executing the transformations individually works as well as the following:

X = MissingData().transform(X);
X = OHEncode().transform(X);
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X);
X = pca.fit_transform(X);

rf = LinearRegression();
rf.fit(X,y)

What do you recommend in this case?

Thanks !

Comment: it's hard to know giving the following info. I recommend you to try the following: 1) move `PCA(n_components=10)` to inside the pipeline and check if it works. 2) remove `StandardScaler` and `StandardScaler` and then apply GS, the next step remove `OHEncode` and test.

Comment: The problem is indeed with OHEncode. It has nothing to do with PCA or StandardScaler.

I think I know the reason: In OHEncode, I one hot encode all the categorical features. The problem with that is that since Cross Val. Only uses a portion of the data to train, it is possible that some categorical values won't show up in the training and thus won't get encoded, so there will be a problem when we try to predict them.

Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with that? I'm probably not the first person to face this problem. Should I give up using Pipeline for this part of the processing?

Comment: Good, now the issue is clear. I suggest you to edit your question and add these final details about the error, for a better archiving ;).

Answer (score 1):

The first point, I would should you to use `OneHotEncoder` (OHE) class from sklearn. Then, define in the constructor of `OHEncode` an object of OHE and fit it with the all categorical values you have (to make them "seen" at each GridSearch iteration). Then in `transform` fuction of `OHEncode`, apply transform using the object of OHE.

DON'T fit the OHE object Inside the `fit` function because then you will have the same error; at each GridSearch iteration, the fit and transform functions are applied.

Comment: Good ideia. There's one problem though. OneHotEncoder from sklearn doesn't handle missing values. And I'm starting to think I don't really know how Pipeline works. I'm running in the following issue when I try your suggestion:

Comment: Works:
X_ = MissingData().transform(X) ; 
pipeline = Pipeline([('OHEncode', OHEncode(X_)),('scaler', StandardScaler()) , ('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1))]) works but the following doesn't: X_ = MissingData().transform(X) ;
pipeline = Pipeline([('missingdata', MissingData()),('OHEncode', OHEncode(X_)),('scaler', StandardScaler()) , ('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1))])
If I have imputed the missing values already, adding MissingValues to my pipeline shouldn't make any difference, but I get the error: 'Input contains NaN'

Comment: Impute the missing data also using sklearn imputer, here it's: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

create a pipeline in the constructor of `OHEncode` with both `OneHotEncoder` and `SimpleImputer` and fit it only .. later on apply transform

Comment: I'm already using SimpleImputer. Why should I do both One Hot encoding and Imputing in the  OHEncode constructor? Do you have any ideas on why my approach isn't working? As far as I've tested, my MissingData() function is working fine, it always gives back data without any mission value.

Comment: I didn't notice that in yor code. Did you try to fit the `OneHotEncoder` in the constructor? .. to follow my solution?